# Excel 2010 find/lookup based on table Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a Excel (Office2010) range table as per following

[image]

using excel formulas (no VBA) how do i find

- What subjects "Jane" has completed?
- Who has done "Spanish"

i have tried few types of vlookup,hlookup index/match without having any luck
any help would be much appreciated.
Due to Office 2010 i cannot use TEXTJOIN function (as answered by @Louis Ries)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are the names in row 1 and and subjects in column A?

Comment: My apologies, yes Table Starts in A1. I have updated th eimage

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution in Excel 2016, but after extensive research, I've found no way to select the data and eliminate values that don't match with formulas, and no VBA or add-ins. I'm quite interested in learning a solution for this that is compatible with previous versions of excel, but don't believe I'll find one anytime soon. My best suggestion is to obsolesce your version of Excel for 2016.

---

**If you are using Excel 2016:**

Note: I created a copy of the data and inserted it as a Table("Table1") with headers.

1. Enter this into a cell as an array formula(CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER).
   It will retrieve all subjects that Jane has completed.

   > =TEXTJOIN("; ",1,REPT(Table1[Subject],1*(Table1[Jane]="x")))

---

2. Enter this into a cell as an array formula (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER).
   It will retrieve all headers where the row you desire has an x.

   > =TEXTJOIN("; ",1,REPT(Table1[#Headers],1*(A4:F4="x")))

   If you select a row and create an alias(i.e. select A4:F4 and in name manger, alias it as Spanish), you can use this. (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

   > =TEXTJOIN("; ",1,REPT(Table1[#Headers],1*(Spanish="x")))

Comment: Unfortunately no access to TEXTJOIN formula as i'm using Office2010

Comment: Hi @Louis Reis
CONCAT is not available in Excel 2010, is it possible to use CONCATENATE alternatively?

Comment: My bad, I had it in Excel as CONCATENATE, but typed CONCAT here. No, sorry.. just checked, it didn't work using CONCATENATE in Excel 2013. It only gave the first match, didn't concatenate the other matches. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: I copied array formula to several cells but only returning "Maths" as the result as you said

Comment: Copied =REPT(Table1[Subject],1*(Table1[Jane]="x")) down in a row and it does give the correct responses

Comment: Copied =REPT(Table1[#Headers],1*(B4:G4="x")) across a row and it gives correct reponses